# Maximum norm matrix. Show (In)equalities.

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $ A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ be matrices . $ x \in \mathbb{R^n} $ . $ || A || := max_{1 \le i \le n } \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}| . $ and $ |x| $:= max{$ |x_1|, ... , |x_n|$ } .

Show that:

1) $ ||A|| $ = $ sup_{|x|=1} |Ax| $

2) $ ||A + B || \le ||A|| + ||B|| $

3) $|Ax| \le ||A|| |x| $

4) $||AB || \le ||A|| ||B|| $

**Attempt**:

I think, that I have 2) and 3).
For example 2) : $ |Ax| = max_{i}| \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{ik} x_k|  $ Now use triangle inequality , estimate again and we are done.
 Can you please give me a hint for 1) and 4)?

Answer (score 1):

For 1:

\begin{align}
|Ax|
= \max_{1 \le i \le n} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j\right|
\le \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}| =: \|A\|.
\end{align}
Hint to prove the above: for a fixed $i$, show that $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j\right| \le \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|$$ for any $x$ satisfying $|x| = 1$, and that equality is attained if we choose $x_j := \text{sign}(a_{ij})$. Then take the maximum over $i$ on both sides.

---

For 4: using #1, we have

$$\|AB\| = \sup_{|x|=1} |ABx| = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{|ABx|}{|x|} \le \|A\|\sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{|Bx|}{|x|} = \|A\|\|B\|.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand your point. But I have two little questions. I hope that they are not obvious. First one: how do I know that $ sup_{x=1} |Ax|  = sup_{ x not 0} \frac{|Ax|}{|x|} $. Second one: I said that I showed the inequality for A+B. Now I see your solution for A*B. You used 1). Could I you 1) also for A+B. ? I'm just curious. :)

Comment: @Mugumble Since $y/|y|$ satisfies $|(y/|y|)|=1$, you can rewrite $\sup_{|x|=1}|Ax|$ as $\sup_{y \ne 0} |A(y/|y|)|$.

Comment: @Mugumble Yes you could use #1 to prove #2.